Could wormholes become stable at some point during the Big rip of the universe?
Does the extreme expansion of the universe have an effect on wormholes?

There is no evidence suggesting a Big Rip is coming.

I'm aware. There are no wormholes either as far as we know. This is a hypothetical question.
